# Send http request for local resources in offline mode

Tags: javascript

I am working on a website that should work `offline`(without network connectivity).

My problem is that when I disable network via chrome developer tools, I can't send `http` requests for local resources.

Is there a way to send `http` request in offline mode for local resources(`images` , `json`, etc...)?

Comment: You don't, you ask for those resources. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/storing-data-on-the-client-with-localstorage

Comment: So there is no way without local storage?

Comment: You'd have to use Caching on the client side, you can totally do that with ApplicationCache.

Comment: OK, thank's @Leonard and paul, I was hoping to not use cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use caching on the client side.

For persiting JSON objects you can use **localStorage**, you can also use **[LocalForage](https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/)** to wrap localStorage, indexedDB and WebSQL.

If you need to cache resources, like images, CSS stylesheets or HTML pages, you can use the (currently deprecated) **[ApplicationCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)**, or **[ServiceWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)**.